# Getting mac from HMAC value and key

Tags: encryption, sha, hmac

I am looking at this page on how to validate HMAC implementation on a platform: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/

```
Test Vectors:
HMAC Test Vectors - These files provide an electronic version of the test vectors
that can be used to informally verify the correctness of an HMAC algorithm 
implementation using the HMACVS. However, use of these vectors does not
take the place of validation obtained through the Cryptographic Algorithm
Validation Program (CAVP).
```

So I open up the file and view the test values:
http://pastebin.com/phJ4C0Fx
it is thousands of lines long but this is the start.

I focus on the first values:

```
[L=20]

Count = 0
Klen = 10
Tlen = 10
Key = 82f3b69a1bff4de15c33
Msg = fcd6d98bef45ed6850806e96f255fa0c8114b72873abe8f43c10bea7c1df706f10458e6d4e1c9201f057b8492fa10fe4b541d0fc9d41ef839acff1bc76e3fdfebf2235b5bd0347a9a6303e83152f9f8db941b1b94a8a1ce5c273b55dc94d99a171377969234134e7dad1ab4c8e46d18df4dc016764cf95a11ac4b491a2646be1
Mac = 1ba0e66cf72efc349207
```

My understanding is that with a key and value that openssl would get the mac, however I am not getting the same mac as that above?

```
echo -n "<Msg here>" | openssl sha1 -hmac "82f3b69a1bff4de15c33"
(stdin)= 981c64f70b07634e01b3800447e6431dddb42530
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? i am also just guessing sha1, other values don't match either, I don't know how to take from the file what way I should be doing this. The various lengths, and the count. How do I use this information?

Comment: See [RFC 2104](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2104) to understand the notation. The test vectors are given in hex but they need to be converted to binary prior to being used, depending on the tool you are using. Use the [-macopt hexhey](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dgst.html#) option to specify a hex key with the openssl command line tool

Comment: @GregS I converted both values to binary but it was also wrong, will have a read through the doc to understand, thanks!

Comment: `echo -n "fcd6d98bef45ed6850806e96f255fa0c8114b72873abe8f43c10bea7c1df706f10458e6d4e1c9201f057b8492fa10fe4b541d0fc9d41ef839acff1bc76e3fdfebf2235b5bd0347a9a6303e83152f9f8db941b1b94a8a1ce5c273b55dc94d99a171377969234134e7dad1ab4c8e46d18df4dc016764cf95a11ac4b491a2646be1" | xxd -r -p |  ~/bin/openssl dgst -sha1 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:82f3b69a1bff4de15c33` on my Mac gives the correct, albeit untruncated, answer.

Comment: Hi @GregS When I enter that I get `35509ad9f0dd5da08dd47adb488e692ae4d1f8b8` What do you get? As far as i'm aware the answer above shouldn't be truncated as it is an answer in a Known Answer Test.

Comment: Thanks for showing me xxd I didn't know that existed, also I'm doing thins on ubuntu.

Comment: I get `(stdin)= 1ba0e66cf72efc34920713e94f73e4cbbcd55f9f`. If you just copy and paste from my comment you have to delete some extra spaces that get put in.

Comment: @GregS Very strange, I must be doing something silly http://i.imgur.com/v2Bg7bE.png Will try and figure out the difference thanks

Comment: Can anybody please tell me what `Tlen` means?

Comment: I think I found it. `Tlen` means partial leading output, right? Trimmed? Target?

Comment: @Jin Kwon, yes, I think "Truncated" MAC len.  That said, some Tlens are longer than SHA1 and it isn't clear to me which lines in the HMAC.rsp are using SHA1 and which are SHA2 or 3.  It seems we need the missing HMAC.req file to actually validate these vectors.